# Python Numpy Array Ctypes Pointer

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, ctypes

I have a GetImageData function in a DLL:

```
int GetImageData ( const char * name , int ID , const char * strLibPath , int Lvl , int rbeg , int rend , int cbeg , int cend , int ZLayer , unsigned char * ImgBuffer );
```

in Python I import this DLL and establish the variables:

```
import ctypes,numpy          
from ctypes import *          
Wlib = ctypes.WinDLL('C:\\...\\Wsl.dll')    
GetImage=Wlib["GetImage"]

name =c_char_p(fname)
ID =c_int(0)
strLibPath=c_char_p(LibPath)
Lvl =c_int(0)
rbeg =c_int(100)
rend =c_int(1099)
cbeg =c_int(5500)
cend =c_int(6499)
ZLayer =c_int(0)
nBpp=24
nch  = nBpp/8
roiW = 6499-5500+1
roiH = 1099-100+1
```

In MATLAB an array and pointer are defined:

```
img = uint8(zeros([roiW,roiH,nch]));
ptr = libpointer('uint8Ptr',img);
```

In PYTHON I think this is how it should be done for the Matlab equivalent, but this does not work and kills Python:

```
img = numpy.zeros([roiW,roiH,nch],dtype=ctypes.c_int8)
ptr=img.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int8))
[status, fname, fpath, img]=GetImage(name,ID,strLibPath,Lvl,rbeg,rend,cbeg,cend,ZLayer, ptr)
```

How do I correctly create an array and pointer than can be fed to my DLL?

Comment: Shouldn't the return type be an integer? Why do you have `[status, fname, fpath, img]`?

Comment: @bdforbes I had originally done this because the Matlab wrapper had done this with `[status, fname, fpath, img] = calllib('WholeImg','GetImage', name, ID, strLibPath, Lvl, rbeg, rend,cbeg,cend,Zlayer,ptr)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually creating all the `c_int` and `c_char_p` instances is unnecessary. But set the function pointer's `argtypes` to enable type checking.

The `ctypes._as_parameter_` attribute of NumPy arrays is a `c_void_p`. If you prefer more strict type safety, use `POINTER(c_uint8)` in `argtypes` and `data_as`.

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

__all__ = ['GetImage']

# WinDLL is stdcall; use CDLL for cdecl.
Wlib = WinDLL(r'C:\...\Wsl.dll') 

Wlib.GetImage.argtypes = ([c_char_p, c_int, c_char_p] + 
                          [c_int] * 6 + 
                          [c_void_p])

def GetImage(name, ID, strLibPath, Lvl=0, 
             rbeg=100, rend=1099, 
             cbeg=5500, cend=6499, 
             ZLayer=0, nBpp=24):
    roiW = cend - cbeg + 1
    roiH = rend - rbeg + 1
    nch = nBpp // 8
    img = np.zeros([roiW, roiH, nch], dtype=np.uint8)
    ImgBuffer = img.ctypes
    status = Wlib.GetImage(name, ID, strLibPath, Lvl,
                           rbeg, rend, cbeg, cend, 
                           ZLayer, ImgBuffer)
    # test status
    return img
```

I use `from ctypes import *` for convenience. You can import the wrapped C API into another module to get a clean namespace. It's common in Python to have one or more support modules and platform modules named with an initial underscore.

Comment: Thank you! I'm learning how to use Ctypes. I guess the problem I have now is how to determine errors with the DLL. After running the `Wlib.GetImage()`, Python dies without any errors, the Windows stopped working error comes up, and I can't make any sense from the Windows text error log. Is there a better way to test my DLL function and connection?

Comment: Try reversing the order of the width and height: `img = np.zeros([roiH, roiW, nch], dtype=np.uint8)`.  I missed that earlier. MATLAB uses Fortran-style column-major arrays, but NumPy defaults to C-style row-major arrays.

Comment: I have the right function, it is GetImage. There was an error in the documentation, two of the variables `int ID , const char * strLibPath` are not supposed to be in the GetImage function. Now the program does not crash, but I get an `access violation reading 0x0000000000000064` error that I am going to work on now. Thanks for your help, it pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: Assuming 64-bit, `0x0000000000000064` is the value for `rbeg` on the call stack. It looks like it's expecting a pointer for the argument index of `strLibPath`. Assuming you've eliminated `ID` and `strLibPath` from the call, change `rbeg` to 108 and see if the access violation changes with it to address `0x6c`. If so the documentation is either correct or completely unreliable. ;)

Comment: Yes, the access violation is now 0x6c.

Comment: So probably `int ID, const char *strLibPath` is correct. Can I read the source online somewhere, or is this proprietary, closed-source software?